# Actionview Template Error when sending actionmailer e-mail - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm getting an error anytime I try and send out an e-mail to users. The below is sent out every day at noon:

```
    <% @user.account.ideas.each do |idea| %> #this is the line that errors
    <%= idea.title %>
    <% end %>
```

Here's the error:

```
    scheduler caught exception :
    ActionView::Template::Error
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport- 3.0.7/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in     `method_missing'
```

I think it's something with the email not being able to interact with controllers... any thoughts? I'm lost. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the fact that the warning comes out of `whiny_nil.rb`, I'm willing to bet that `@user.account` is returning `nil` rather than an actual `Account` object. Search through your database for users without an account, I reckon there's at least one.

Comment: In my models, Users belong to accounts, so there isn't an account column in the user model, just account_id... But the account also has_many ideas through Users, and I'm trying to display all of the ideas from the account. Does that help at all?